Will a plane 'shake' when it stalls?
I haven't been able to confirm this, but does a plane shake when it stalls? If so, why?
I was able to find some info on this, but from a non-confirmed source.

As the plane shakes and rattles, it's a telltale sign that something is awry with the airflow over the wings.

From here.

I've also heard of this happening when the plane is maneuvering / pulling hard. (for example a fighter jet in a dogfight)
Does this actually happen, and if so, why?
(My assumption is that it's due to the turbulence over the wings when maneuvering or in a stall)

... and this turbulence hitting the tail, yes.

@PeterKämpf That would definitely make sense, thanks.


Will a plane 'shake' when it stalls?

Yes - for the simple reason that it has been designed to do so.
When designing an airplane (at least of conventional shape i.e. with a fuselage, a wing and a tailplane) the wing is laid out so that at high AoA the root stalls first while the center sections and its tips continue to produce lift.
This is beneficial in two ways: the stalled wake living the root impinges on the tailplane making it shake and warning the pilot about the imminent stall. Plus the ailerons and the other movable surfaces located on the outer part of the wing keep on working and the airplane remains maneuverable.

Riding onboard the 747-400 during stall testing, for example, I can assure you - it shook! The short answer upfront is the unsteady nature of separated flow, especially when coupled with a (relatively) flexible wing. Think of how you are buffeted when driving behind a large truck on the highway. Obviously, the frequency and amplitude of buffeting will vary with aircraft, loading and flight condition. I've heard a distinguished fighter test pilot say repeatable buffet characteristics are a good cue regarding angle-of-attack and energy state - "tactically useful" he said.

So let’s look at your question briefly from the standpoint of a high performance propeller driven aircraft.  Herein is shown the V-n diagram for this aircraft across the flight envelope for velocity $V$ and wing loading $n$ from sea level to altitude (40k ft).  The source is Dommasch, et. al, 1967.  This flight envelope is dynamic and expands to its maximum structural and velocity limits at sea level, or shrinks to its more limited range of flight conditions at altitude.  The notation defining n literally means the wing loading in $g$ units.  Hence, this is also called a V-g diagram.
Among the salient features to the question at hand are the limiting conditions noted for $n = (V/V_s)^2$ shown for maneuvers incurring both positive and negative wing loadings.  These are the stall limits.  Velocities shown in this diagram indicate true speeds in mph, and under the stall-limiting conditions shown in the diagram, would indicate stalling speeds.  For instance, an attempt at sea level to perform a maneuver at 200 mph which will sustain a wing loading of 5g will result in a stall.  Under such conditions, think turbulent separation and consequent buffeting resulting from the stall.  Further, a sea-level attempt to incur a loading exceeding 8g at 300 mph will result in damage to, or failure of the aircraft structure. The element of greatest concern, in this case, is the wing.  Now think about the consequences of incurring a stall under these dynamic and exceedingly harsh flight conditions in a lower-elevation, high-density atmosphere. Wing flexure and stall buffeting can be extreme.  Notice also that at higher velocities, for flight conditions that are well away from the stall-limiting velocities, wing loadings can be incurred that exceed the structural limit.
Notice now at higher velocities the indicated buffet limit due to the presence of Mach shocks on the wings.  These buffeting conditions are incurred across the range of flight conditions at the limiting velocity of the aircraft.  Notice also that favorable for the pilot at altitude, the aircraft can develop its full range of flight performance without incurring wing loadings and stresses that would result in structural failure.  But also notice that under these conditions, the aircraft will be pressed to its limits both in exceeding limiting lift coefficients and g loadings thereby resulting in stall, or otherwise in limiting velocities resulting in Mach buffeting.  Such conditions, of course, can be seen to become more hazardous as altitude decreases toward sea level (as indicated above).

